# Make kafka consumer group inactive

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

My biggest question is that do we have a concept in kafka called as **consumer group** to be inactive/active.

I am not sure how to achieve this in my local kafka server.

Can anyone help in how to do the kafka consumer group to inactive/active state?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Confluent Control Center, you can see consumer section , if 'number of consumers' column is 0 then consumer group is inactive and visa versa

[Confluent Control Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Upfr.png)

Answer (score -1):

If you have an **active** Consumer that is reading message, and the offsets are being commited back to Kafka, then you can confidently say, that is in an active state, as far as the Consumer Group is concerned.

If the group is rebalancing, consumers die periodically, or there is no more any consumers reading from a topic, then it is inactive.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please tell me how can we configure the consumergroup as inactive?

Comment: You need to track down and find the active consumers and stop them. There is no way to do that externally.

Comment: `Error: Assignments can only be reset if the group 'some-group' is inactive, but the current state is PreparingRebalance.`